# How to iterate through string for all regexp matches in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

We have a string: "`<b><c><d><e>`"

And this Regexp: `/<(\w+)>/i`

How can I get ALL of the matches from current string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"<b><c><d><e>".scan(/<(\w+)>/)
```

See [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) on ruby-docs

Comment: The `i` is not needed in this case.

Comment: Tha `i` was in the question, so it's not really up to answerer to remove it.

Comment: Sure it is since the `i` has no effect on `\w`.

Comment: I re-added the trailing backslash for the regex literal, you probably removed it when removing the `i`.